# Bootstrap button in form control changes directly to disabled

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I'm using Bootstrap 5.0 and as soon as I turn a button into a .form-control, the button is immediately and automatically disabled and grayed out. If I move the mouse over the button, it is displayed correctly to me: e.g. btn btn-primary

// the left button is without a .form-control and the right button has a .form-control

[image: Screenshot Buttons here]

// This is what I found

[image: Screenshot css file here]

Can someone tell me, why is that happens? Never had this issue before.

Comment: The difference between these two buttons is only `.form-control`?Can you share your html code?

Comment: I've found that when I'm using bootstrap 5.0 then this problem occurs. As soon as I use bootstrap 4.6 it works. I don't change anything in the HTML style code.

Is there a change in bootstrap 5.0 that does it automatically?